# Time getting printed as '0x814ff30'

Tags: go

Learning go lang. Might be a basic question.

I have an time.Time object and I wanted to get the epoch time for it. What I write to get that is :

```
fmt.Println(startTime.Unix)
```

where startTime is an object of time.Time. Now, I would have expected it to print some big number, something as, 1257894000, but what I get is : **0x814ff30**.

Did not understand why? Would be happy to write more in case it is not clear.

Comment: `Unix` is a function and you are printing the function (i.e. its address), not the value `Unix`would produce if you would invoke the function as in `Unix()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`time.Unix()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Unix) function

```
fmt.Println(time.Now().Unix())
//1479454089
```

Comment: Aaah. I missed the "()" after Unix. So lame! Thanks anyway.